# Assign String variable to an String array

Tags: java

I am not able to assign a String variable to a String Array. 
My code is :

```
//Declaring a String array 
public String [] fileWrite = new String [10]; 

//assigning a variable 

String value = String.valueOf(aChar1);
fileWrite[0] = value;
```

But when I try to print the array, it gives `null`. I checked the value of variable **value** but that is ok. I cant understand the reason of array being `null`.

Comment: I fear that too much information is missing here. Please show how you print the array, and tell us just what aChar1 is.

Comment: Can you provide a [short, complete, compilable example program](http://sscce.org) that ehibits your issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you need to know that "printing an array" in java is somewhat "broken": You need to use [`Arrays.toString(array)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) to print an array (you can't rely on `array.toString()` - it isn't useful).

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] fileWrite = new String[10];
    char aChar1 = 'x';
    String value = String.valueOf(aChar1);
    fileWrite[0] = value;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileWrite));
}
```

Output:

```
[x, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String[] fileWrite = new String[10];
fileWrite[0] = aChar1 + "";
```

Try this

Comment: What could this possibly do to help?

Answer (score 0):

The assign is correct. Maybe the variable **aChar1** is null or the string "null"

Answer (score 0):

To assign a variable to an array try

```
    String[] fileWrite = new String[10];
    Arrays.fill(fileWrite, aChar1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileWrite));
```